# Accessing Java hashmap to get subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, hashmap, subclass

I am intializing one hashmap which contains key and subclass object.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public Map<Locale, XlsxParserBase> getXlsxParserMap() {
    Map<Locale, XlsxParserBase> xlsxParserMap = Maps.newHashMap();
    xlsxParserMap.put(Locale.US, new com.us.XlsxParser()); 
    xlsxParserMap.put(Locale.EU, new com.eu.XlsxParser());
    return xlsxParserMap;
}
```

This map gets intialized when the server starts. Now I have a manager class which has the locale. I just want to do

```
xlsxParserMap.get(locale).parse();
```

where each subclass has parse implementation and uses common methods from base. When I do this, i am unable to access parse beacause parse method is not present in superclass. Since, map is of type (Locale, XlsxParserBase), I am unable to access child methods from XlsxParserBase reference.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this? I do not want to put instanceOf in manager class. To avoid that, i thought of this map approach. Do experts have some better approach for my problem? Let me know if I am unclear or you need more snippets.

Answer (score 0):

There are some possibilities:

1. add a `parse()` method to your `XlsxParserBase` and make the concrete classes implement/override it in their `parse()` method.
2. go with reflection. Retrieve the `parse` method from the `XlsxParserBase` class in the map an call this. `Method method = obj.getClass().getMethod("parse");  method.invoke(obj);`.
3. create a wrapper (e.g. `XlsxParserWrapper`) class which contains a `parse()` method. This method in concretete implementations (e.g. `XlsxParserWrapperUS`) calls the underlying concrete implementation (e.g. `com.us.XlsxParser().parse()`).
4. hassle with `instanceof`

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface that has a parse() method (and possibly others) and let all subclasses implement the interface.

Then you can have a collection of this interface and the manager class can have a method with that interface as parameter